# Center/Align TextView with text embedded in CheckedTextView

Tags: android, layout, checkedtextview

The following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <CheckedTextView
        android:text="SYSTEM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:checked="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

produces this:

[image]

But preference is to have the HEADER text centered with the SYSTEM text. Obviously the fact that the checkbox is embedded throws the alignment of the text off. I've tried experimenting using the CheckedTextView for the HEADER text as well, but we don't want the checkbox to appear in the HEADER and have not been able to figure out how to make it disappear. Any ideas on how to center align HEADER and SYSTEM while still using the CheckedTextView?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <CheckedTextView
        android:text="SYSTEM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:checked="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not center the texts on each other... and it collapsed the width of the CheckedTextView which needs to stay matching the parent view (there will be multiple CheckedTextViews in a column so all checkboxes need to align)